# iOS- Interface Builder - Scrolling stays on the same position

Tags: ios, interface-builder, scrollview

Possibly, this question is completely easy for iOS gurus but not for freshers like me.

I have made a ScrollView with Interface Builder and it seems to scroll but jumps back, to the top level all the time. Hence, it is impossible to scroll down and read the text on the bottom level.

I made a short video of the problem for visualisation of the problem: https://gph.is/2QI5mie

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Check the content size of the scroll view. You need set the content size, if it is greater than the bounds, to make a scroll view scroll.

Comment: Looks like the content under scroll view not creating proper `contentSize` height. Check your constraints
For debugging purpose try adding `height` to scroll view more than your device screen height just for debugging purpose.

Comment: are you using constraints or auto resizing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollveiw’s setContentOffset. It will scroll where you want.

scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: a, y: b), animated: true)

If you want to scroll to bottom it b will be scrollView.frame.size.height